# Safari issues with padding calc

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues getting my padding calc() to display properly inside of Safari.

```
<div class"menu-container">
 <div class="menu-padding-container"></div>
</div>
```

```
.menu-padding-container {
  padding: 45px calc((100% - 1300px) / 2) 55px;
}
```

It's displaying fine in every browser apart from Safari.

If I remove the inside brackets to (100% - 1300px / 2) then it displays fine on Safari but not on other browsers.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ```-webkit-calc()``` did you try this? Calc is not supported with all browsers

Comment: This doesn't work. Both Safari and Chrome use -webkit-calc() resulting in the same issue as before. I tried both -webkit-calc(100% - 1300px / 2) and -webkit-calc((100% - 1300px) / 2)

Comment: Did you try putting it in its own property ```padding-right:calc(100% - 1300px / 2);```

Comment: Also we can refer to pemdas about your calc equation. Not sure if that may be a issue because not exactly sure what you are aiming ```100% - 650px``` would be what your calc results in, but some browsers may calc it as ```((100% - 1300px) / 2)```